# BeagleBone Black - b.pinMode in for loop

Tags: javascript, beagleboneblack

I recently got a BBB and have been experimenting, but have found out that sometimes my programs still run in the background, so some digital outs are still set to high. I decided to try to fix that by writing a sort of reset program that would iterate through and set all the pins to `b.LOW`. My code is as follows:

```
var b = require("bonescript");

var port = "P8_0";

for(var i = 0; i < 46; i++){
    var j = i + 1;
    port = port.substring(0, 3) + j;
    b.pinMode(port, b.OUTPUT);
    b.digitalWrite(port, b.LOW);
}
```

Here's where it gets interesting. I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/bonescript/index.js:195
    throw('Invalid pin object for pinMode: ' + pin);
                                            ^
Invalid pin object for pinMode: [object Object]
```

Based on what I've seen in terms of setting the pin mode, the only thing that is the problem here is that `pinMode` is inside the `for` loop, and that Cloud9 doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as I was typing the question, I had a brainwave hit me. The reason the code doesn't work is because you can't start from pin 1. Pins 1 and 2 are reserved, because 2 is ground, and 1 is for something else. So if we change the code to this:

```
var b = require("bonescript");

var port = "P8_0";

for(var i = 2; i < 46; i++){
    var j = i + 1;
    port = port.substring(0, 3) + j;
    b.pinMode(port, b.OUTPUT);
    b.digitalWrite(port, b.LOW);
}
```

Works totally fine.